# How to create a Mongodb atlas project alert that targets multiple specific hosts?

Tags: mongodb-atlas

Mongodb Atlas allows project alerts to target specific hosts by `Hostname` or `Hostname And Port`. The [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/cloud-manager/tutorial/manage-alert-configurations/#optional-apply-the-alert-only-to-specific-targets) states *"you can optionally filter the alert to apply only to a subset of the targets. The filter uses a logical OR operator between each condition."*

When I try and add multiple hostnames, they appear with AND operators in the UI which obviously won't ever match.

[Mongodb Atlas alert target hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls2Jo.png)

When testing the above configuration, the alerts were never triggered.

**Is there any way of specifying an OR condition to target multiple hosts via full hostname (no wildcards or regex) in a single alert?**

I am trying to automate the creation of alerts via terraform and only have a list of hostnames so can't easily use the `matches` (regex) or `starts with` options to target hosts with patterns. To add to this, the hostnames don't always include the cluster names so can't build up a matching string myself.

I have tried adding the hostnames in a csv or semi-colon-separated list without luck, the alerts were never triggered.

Another option is to create an alert per host, but that leads on to terraform issues where it is doesn't know the number of hosts at plan time so can't proceed. The suggested fix for this is to split it into different stacks, run the DB first then the alerts but this is fitting into an existing workflow so isn't possible to do. It would also make many more alerts than required.